# counting changes in row elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with a dataset with strings in a column, and I need to count the number of changes in the data frame for that column. So if the data frame were grouped by column 'id', one group instance would look like the example below:

```
    id    vehicle
   'abc'  'bmw'
   'abc'  'bmw'
   'abc'  'yamaha'
   'abc'  'suzuki'
   'abc'  'suzuki'
   'abc'  'kawasaki'
```

So in this case, I would like to be able to say that id 'abc' changed vehicle brand 3 times. Is there an efficient way to do this over multiple groups for column 'id'?

Comment: Access the `vehicle` of each id and pass the list to `set()` you will get distinct vehicles for the given id.

Comment: That doesn't do what I am asking. I don't need the unique values. I need the number of times they changed. Unique values are 4, changes however are 3.

Comment: simply iterate over the vehicles for given id and increment a variable if the next value is not equal to current, where are you exactly facing the problem ?

Comment: this is an extremely simplified example. The actual dataset has a million rows and hundreds of groups (by id). Looping will take an eternity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways:

1) [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'id' and call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) on the 'vehicle' column and pass method `nunique`, you have to subtract 1 as you are looking for changes rather than just an overall unique count:

```
In [292]:
df.groupby('id')['vehicle'].nunique() -1

Out[292]:
id
'abc'    3
Name: vehicle, dtype: int64
```

2) [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) a lambda that tests whether the current vehicle does not equal the previous vehicle using [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift), this is more semantically correct as this detects changes rather than just the overall unique count, calling [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html#pandas.Series.sum) on booleans will convert `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively:

```
In [293]:
df.groupby('id')['vehicle'].apply(lambda x: x != x.shift()).sum() - 1

Out[293]:
3
```

The `-1` is required on the above as for the first row it will compare with a row that doesn't exist and comparisons with `NaN` don't make sense in this case see below:

```
In [301]:
df.groupby('id')['vehicle'].apply(lambda x: x != x.shift())

Out[301]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
Name: 'abc', dtype: bool
```

Comment: This works. I knew a lambda had to be used somehow, just didn't think of using the shift function. Thank you!